# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `lg` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This code is responsible for displaying the components on the page. But in the console I get the following warnings:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `lg` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`, expected one of type [number, boolean].

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `sm` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`, expected one of type [number, boolean].

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `xs` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`, expected one of type [number, boolean].

As I understand it, I'm using Grid incorrectly. But I still can’t figure out how to transfer this one so as not to destroy this page markup. Please tell me how to get rid of these warnings

```
    const GridProps = {
    container: true,
    xs: '12', sm: '7', lg: '9',
}

export default function Devices() {
    const urlParams = useParams();

    return (
        <Grid className={classes.containerStyle}>
            
            <Grid className={classes.widthAndHeight}>
                <Grid {...GridProps}>
                    
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop lg supplied to ForwardRef(Grid), expected one of type [number, boolean].

The **Grid** component expects  `lg, md, sm`  in these options **number** or **boolean** type, and you are using a **string** type.

> lg = 'auto' | number | bool [Grid Props](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/grid/#props)

Correct should be:

```js
const GridProps = {
  container: true,
  xs: 12,
  sm: 7,
  lg: 9,
  item: true,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing it this way :) But in this case I have another warning: Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `lg` of `Grid` can only be used together with the `item` prop.

Comment: @Paul Add `item: true` in the **GridProps**. I updated snippet.